# TypeError: Reflect.getMetadata is not a function When using Node.JS routing-controller

Tags: node.js, express, routing-controllers

I am getting the following error. Can anyone please help

D:\Learning\Node\r-controller\node_modules\src\metadata\ParamMetadata.ts:120
const ParamTypes = (Reflect as any).getMetadata('design:paramtypes', args.object, args.method);
^
TypeError: Reflect.getMetadata is not a function
at new ParamMetadata (D:\Learning\Node\r-controller\node_modules\src\metadata\ParamMetadata.ts:120:43)
at D:\Learning\Node\r-controller\node_modules\src\metadata-builder\MetadataBuilder.ts:125:25
at Array.map ()
at MetadataBuilder.createParams (D:\Learning\Node\r-controller\node_modules\src\metadata-builder\MetadataBuilder.ts:125:8)
at D:\Learning\Node\r-controller\node_modules\src\metadata-builder\MetadataBuilder.ts:111:28
at Array.map ()
at MetadataBuilder.createActions (D:\Learning\Node\r-controller\node_modules\src\metadata-builder\MetadataBuilder.ts:108:30)
at D:\Learning\Node\r-controller\node_modules\src\metadata-builder\MetadataBuilder.ts:85:33
at Array.map ()
at MetadataBuilder.createControllers (D:\Learning\Node\r-controller\node_modules\src\metadata-builder\MetadataBuilder.ts:81:24)

Comment: https://github.com/typestack/routing-controllers/issues/669

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add import "reflect-metadata" in your main file

Comment: Tip: it must be exactly `import 'reflect-metadata';`. Doing `import * as reflect from 'reflect-metadata';` didn't work for me.

Comment: also make sure that it is the first import statement in that file